# Remove elements from array based on value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
arr = ['Jack', 'Ross', 'Buggi', 'Mimi', 'Zolo', 'Roy']
```

From this array if want to remove certain values like lets say Buggi and Zolo, how can I do that so that the arr looks something like

```
arr = ['Jack', 'Ross', 'Mimi', 'Roy']
```

Buggie and Zolo are just examples, it can be any element Ross, Roy.

I want to implement this in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `arr.filter()` with a block that defines the defines the items you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Rails, you can use Active Support's [Enumerable.without](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-without) (rails 5) or [Enumerable.excluding](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-excluding) (>= rails 6)

```rb
# Rails 6
arr = ['Buggie', 'Mimi', 'Zolo', 'Roy'].excluding('Buggie', 'Zolo')

# Rails 5
arr = ['Buggie', 'Mimi', 'Zolo', 'Roy'].without('Buggie', 'Zolo')
```